# An AWS Route53 DNS Failover setup using custom domain does not detect when primary health check is unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I've read the AWS documentation on Route53, specifically, the parte related with defining how to setup a DNS failover using custom domain. The steps I followed are these:

1. **Creating an API REST:** I create a simple API REST, configured to be regional, with two endpoints, one with the path */status* that returns a previously read environment variable called STATUS whose value is **FAIL** or **SUCCESS**; and another endpoint with path **/print** that simply prints from which region it is executing the code. I have deployed this API REST on us-east-2 and also in us-west-2.
2. **Requesting certificate for a custom domain:** Since I have bought a domain in AWS using Route53 (for example mydomain.com) I requested a certificate, on us-east-2, for custom domain test.mydomain.com and I successfully validate it using the suggested method (DNS Validation). I repeated this step also for us-west-2 region using the same custom domain.
3. **Create a custom domain:** I use the AWS console for creating custom domain on both regions. Thus, I enter on the API Gateway, on us-east-2 region, and created the custom domain test.mydomain.com, link this domain with the previously requested certificate and also I created a domain mapping to the deployed API REST. I repeated this step also in us-west-2 but using the resources created in this region, that is: the certificate requested in this region as well as the API REST deployed in us-west-2.
4. **Create two Health checks on Route53:** These checks are named EAST and WEST and they use the status endpoint of the API REST deployed in the corresponding region. Thus the check EAST connects to the API REST deployed in us-east-2 region and it consumes the endpoint status.

The EAST health check characteristics are:

```
ID de507044-d8f7-4650-a54a-cb189972361b
URL https://XXX500mdd4.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443/prod/status
Specify endpoint by Domain name
Protocol HTTPS
Domain name adb500mdd4.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Port 443
Path /prod/status
Request interval 10 seconds
Failure threshold 2
Search string SUCCESS
Latency graphs No
Enable SNI Yes
Invert health check status No
Disable health check No
Health checker regions Using recommended health check regions:
```

The WEST health check characteristics are:

```
ID a8e3ce0b-d12c-4408-86fb-2fb13a7bea9d
URL https://sinbpssYYY.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443/prod/status
Specify endpoint by Domain name
Protocol HTTPS
Domain name sinbpssct2.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Port 443
Path /prod/status
Request interval 10 seconds
Failure threshold 2
Search string SUCCESS
Latency graphs No
Enable SNI Yes
Invert health check status No
Disable health check No
Health checker regions Using recommended health check regions
```

1. **Configuring a DNS failover setup:** for this purpose I've created the following two A records, specifying them as alias to an API Gateway:

This is the primary which points at the deployed API REST in the us-east-2 region:

```
Record name: test.mydomain.com
Record type: A
Value: d-vaqdythXXX.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.
Alias: Yes
TTL (seconds): -
Routing policy: Failover
Health check ID: de507044-d8f7-4650-a54a-cb189972361b
```

while this one is the secondary, which in turn it points at the deployed API REST in the us-west-2 region

```
Record name: test.mydomain.com
Record type: A
Value: d-YYY6zowl4f.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
Alias: Yes
TTL (seconds): -
Routing policy: Failover
Health check ID: a8e3ce0b-d12c-4408-86fb-2fb13a7bea9d
```

For testing I employed curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://emission.edx.services/mreg/print'
{"message":"Built from us-east-2 region"}
```

Since initially both health checks are healthy, and being the EAST API the one defined as primary it is expected that the outcome be: "Built from us-east-2 region"}. However, if I redeploy the EAST API REST, changing the environment variable in a way that the status endpoint returns FAIL, resulting in the EAST Health check to be unhealthy, I would expect that the DNS Failover routine executes the API in the secondary (That's the one deployed in us-west-2) however the outcome message keeps the same:

```
{"message":"Built from us-east-2 region"}
```

That is, the failover setup is unable to detects when the primary is down and to use the secondary server. I executed the curl again after 15 minutes and got the same outcome.

**EDIT#1:**

The API REST I've deployed consists on 2 endpoint:

1. a GET endpoint with path "/status" that simple returns the value of an environment variable called STATUS, together with http status code 200.
2. a POST endpoint with path /print" that simple return a string message describing the region from which the endpoint is executing. This way in us-eas-2 this endpoint will return "Built from us-east-2 region"

Each Health check requests at its corresponding GET endpoint and search for the string SUCCESS. IF it find this value then the check is Healthy, otherwise it is unhealthy.

For example, I deployed the API REST with both east and west checks as "healthy", consult the endpoint "/print" with curl and as expected it gives me the message that it is accessing from the us-east-2 region. Well, for testing purpose I edit the EAST health check and I invert health check, thus now since it returns SUCCESS and I've invert its results the Health check is in an unhealthy status. This way I would expect that when I execute the curl command using the domain url it returns that it is executing from us-west-2. However it keeps answering me the same "Built from us-east-2 region" message for at least 30 more minutes.

It turn really weird that I didn't check the url for nearly 4 hours and now I run curl and it is answering "Built from us-west-2 region"!!! It seems that after some hours the failover setup works? buy why it tooks so long to work??

Does anybody know which could be the cause of this strange behavior?

Comment: Show a test that has a failure result. Your demo performs an HTTP POST request. Health checks perform an HTTP GET request.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I've edited the post adding a more detailed description about the test I run and also about the endpoint of the API REST as well as I've included information regarding to the Health checks.